# Задача callback

Tags: javascript

Дополни функцию makeMessage таким образом, чтобы она ожидала вторым параметром (параметр callback) колбек-функцию и возвращала ее вызов. Функция deliverPizza или makePizza будет передаваться как колбек и ожидать аргументом имя доставляемой готовой пиццы.

Визвать `makeMessage('Royal Grand', makePizza)` вернуть рядок 'Pizza Royal Grand is being prepared, please wait...' - это сделала.

Вызов `makeMessage('Ultracheese', deliverPizza)` вернуть рядок 'Delivering Ultracheese pizza.
Но вот тут не получаеться,'помогите, что делаю не так?

```
function deliverPizza(pizzaName) {
  return `Delivering ${pizzaName} pizza.`;
}

function makePizza(pizzaName) {
  return `Pizza ${pizzaName} is being prepared, please wait...`;
  
}

// Chande code below this line
function makeMessage(pizzaName, callback) {
  return "Pizza Royal Grand is being prepared, please wait...";
  callback();
}
makeMessage("Ultracheese", deliverPizza);
```

Comment: попробуй так может годится `function makeMessage(pizzaName, callback) {
  return pizzaName === "Ultracheese" ? callback(pizzaName) : callback("Pizza Royal Grand is being prepared, please wait...");
}`

Comment: Спасибо, направили меня на верный путь.function makeMessage(pizzaName, callback) {   
  return pizzaName === "Royal Grand", 'Ultracheese'  ? callback(pizzaName) : callback("Pizza Royal Grand is being prepared, please wait..."); }

Answer (score 2):

Вот ссылка думаю будет полезно почитать https://learn.javascript.ru/function-basics#vozvrat-znacheniya.
Все что находиться после return не будет выполняться. Функция makeMessage должна возвращать callback c названием пиццы.  Ошибка заключалась в функции makeMessage:

```
function makeMessage(pizzaName, callback) {
  return "Pizza Royal Grand is being prepared, please wait...";
  callback();
}
```

Вот правильный вариант:

```
function deliverPizza(pizzaName) {
  return `Delivering ${pizzaName} pizza.`;
}

function makePizza(pizzaName) {
  return `Pizza ${pizzaName} is being prepared, please wait...`;
  
}

function makeMessage(pizzaName, callback) {
  return callback(pizzaName);
}

makeMessage("Ultracheese", deliverPizza);
```

Comment: Не работает ((( Не могу понять, что не так. Не могу вызвать и вернуть. Что только не пробывала.

Comment: @protebe я добавил немного описания и выложил полный вариант